# Math software for plotting phase portraits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, systems-of-equations, big-list, math-software

I'm looking for math software which is possible to plot phase portraits for ODE and systems of differential equations.

Is there a software which can create not only simple 2D phase portrait plots but also 3D or even $n$D (with $n>3$) ones? 2D are welcome, too.

Comment: See http://math.rice.edu/~dfield/dfpp.html and http://www.bae.ncsu.edu/people/faculty/seaboch/phase/newphase.html.

Comment: @lhf Thank you for your references.

Comment: @Constructor: Maple and Mathematica can do 3D plots (those are difficult to wrap your head around and there is nothing that will be able to do more than that. You might also want to look into Maxima and SAGE (both free) for general ODE solving, phase portraits, direction fields and much more.

Comment: 4D plots? I want to see them...